# Add custom classes to TinyMCE generated markup

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, plugin-tinymce, html

Is there a way to add custom classes to the markup that the tinyMCE WYSIWYG editor?

Obviously, I could apply any styles by targeting the post/page wrapper, but my concern is getting markup to play well with certain javascript plugins and responsive layout classes. Can the wordpress visual editor be enhanced like that?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it manually, but you can use the WP Super Edit Plugin, which facilitates things a little bit.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-edit/